# Installshield update service using high cpu

Tags: process, installshield

Whenever I start up my computer and start playing games, the process InstallShield Update Service (issch.exe) suddenly starts and uses 15% of the cpu (i7 4790K) power. This instantly impacts the performance of the computer and the framerate in games will go all the way down to 10fps. Killing the process manually through task manager fixes the problem, but whenever I restart the computer it will come back.

Is there a way I can prevent issch.exe from launching or using as much of the cpu?

Comment: this should be moved to superuser.com

Comment: I had the same problem , I think it was a malware or a bitcoin miner , downloading malwarebytes solved the problem.